# Replicating unix kill syntax with python ArgumentParser

Tags: python, unix

I am working on a command shell with the python cmd class and I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the unix `kill` command. I want to be able to type `kill -<signum> <pid>` and have argument parser take the `-<signum>` and store it away. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with ArgumentParser since it seems to want to have all of the flags specified ahead of time and that doesn't seem reasonable with the number of signals there are.

Does anyone have any experience with this and if so how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Why is it unreasonable to get the names of all of the signals ahead of time?  Just inspect all of the symbols in the [`signal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) whose names begin with `SIG` (except for `SIG_DFL` and `SIG_IGN`).

Comment: If it were a unix only command I would definitely be able to do that. However this shell is supposed to work on windows as well. On windows their equivalent of kill doesn't use signals but accepts the exit status as an argument instead. I can do the -s like kill supports as well but I'd like the -number syntax.

Comment: Is it required that you use some sort of pre-packaged argument parser?  You could just parse `sys.argv` yourself.

Comment: Its not strictly required however there will be a point where I am not the person maintaining this code anymore and I'd like to keep all of the argument parsing in the same style so its easier to maintain. Also the cmd class has command handlers of the form do_command with the arguments passed along as a string. So its like getting " ".join(sys.argv[1:]). I considered hand parsing the string for this command and a remote execution command since it requires a -- terminating the commands flags like strace does. It seems that it might be the only way to handle this.